# Firefox tab crashing with html file with videos

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, crash

I have a html file with a table and 32 of this (one in each cell)

```
<td><iframe width="560" height="315" src="./videos/a_movie_264.mp4"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></td>
```

When opening it with firefox, it starts to load the page but then the tab crashes.

This does not happen with Chrome.
Unfortunately the message only says the tab crashed but no clue why.
Why this could be happening?

Comment: Have you checked logs?

Comment: So I tried to replicate your prob, made a 4*8 table and used a random mp4 vid i had. It didn't crash. Although it did slow way too much, but that was the only expected behaviour from an old HDD. It didn't *crash* though...

Comment: I'm guessing, Two possiblities. One, Problem's with the video. Two, You used different video in each cell and your HDD/SSD can't take it and it crashed. Out of which Second is a little more probable, but the chance of first one is also good.

Comment: I think I found a possible reason. I had like 10 tabs open in firefox and none in chrome. Now I am using only one tab and it does not crash...

Comment: Evidently that is the reason. A normal computer can't play 32 videos at once,